# converting linear layout to constraint layout results in view too left

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout, padding, android-constraintlayout

I had this nested linear layouts

```
 <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/has_selected_account"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/account_menu_header_signed_in_vertical_margin"
      android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/account_menu_header_signed_in_vertical_margin"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/close_and_recents"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
    <com.myImage
        android:id="@+id/account_avatar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/account_menu_header_signed_in_avatar_margin_start"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/account_menu_header_signed_in_avatar_margin_end"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/account_menu_header_signed_in_avatar_margin_start"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/account_menu_header_signed_in_avatar_margin_end"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:imageViewSize="@dimen/account_menu_header_signed_in_disc_size"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/account_menu_name_and_display_vertical_padding"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/account_menu_name_and_display_vertical_padding"
        android:orientation="vertical">
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/account_display_name"
          style="@style/AccountDataDisplayName"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="center_vertical"
          tools:text="DisplayNameIsLongSoItShouldBeTruncatedAtSomePoint"/>
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/account_name"
          style="@style/AccountDataAccountName"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
          android:includeFontPadding="false"
          tools:text="emailisverylongaswellwewantittogettruncated@gmail.longdomain.com"/>
    </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>
```

and i wanted to convert it to one constraint layout:

```
    <merge>
      <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/has_selected_account"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@color/google_blue100">
    <com.myView
        android:id="@+id/account_avatar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/account_menu_header_signed_in_avatar_margin_start"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/account_menu_header_signed_in_avatar_margin_end"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/account_menu_header_signed_in_avatar_margin_start"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/account_menu_header_signed_in_avatar_margin_end"
        android:contentDescription="@null"
        app:imageViewSize="@dimen/account_menu_header_signed_in_disc_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/account_display_name_top_padding"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/account_menu_name_and_display_vertical_padding"
        android:background="@color/google_red50"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/account_display_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/account_avatar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_display_name"
        style="@style/AccountDataDisplayName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/google_red100"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/account_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/account_avatar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/account_display_name_top_padding"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        tools:text="DisplayNameIssLongSoItShouldBeTruncatedAtSomePoint"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/account_name"
        style="@style/AccountDataAccountName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/google_green100"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/account_name_bottom_padding"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/account_avatar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/account_display_name"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_default="wrap"
        tools:text="emailisverylongaswellwewantittogettruncated@gmail.longdomain.com"/>
    <View
        android:id="@+id/account_name_bottom_padding"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/account_menu_name_and_display_vertical_padding"
        android:background="@color/google_red50"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/account_avatar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/account_name"/>
  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </merge>
```

The result was almost OK, but the textViews are going too up and too close to the Image view.

here is the new result overlapping the old ui:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea why? or how to solve this?

I have added margin left to the imageView but it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Why would you add a left margin to your ImageView if it's already too close to the TextViews?

Answer (score 0):

Try building a more parallel structure between the `TextViews` in the `LinearLayout` and the ones in the `ConstraintLayout` something like the following. Here I have used a `FrameLayout` to show the overlay better and took some liberties with sizes, but the concept holds for your layout. As you can see from the image, the `TextViews` line up precisely except for the final character which is different between the two sets of `TextViews` to give a visual of the overlay.

[image]

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/account_display_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="DisplayName1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/account_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:text="emailisvery1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/account_display_name2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:text="DisplayName2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/account_name2"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/account_name2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:includeFontPadding="false"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="emailisvery2"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/account_display_name2"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_weight="1" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
</FrameLayout>t>
```